# IMacros: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (Error code: 991)

Tags: imacros

I am trying to edit my javascript code to make it function properly.
I keep getting this syntax error though:
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (Error code: 991)

Here is my script:

```
VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/free_points/twitter.html
URL GOTO=addmefast.com/free_points/twitter.html
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS=30
URL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/free_points/twitter_tweets.html
URL GOTO=addmefast.com/free_points/twitter_tweets.html
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet
WAIT SECONDS=30
URL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/free_points/twitter_retweets.html
URL GOTO=addmefast.com/free_points/twitter_retweets.html
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet
WAIT SECONDS=30
```

Comment: This look like JavaScript to you?

Comment: This is javascript.

The file is a javascript file.

Comment: That's nothing like JavaScript, so if you include it in a JS file and try to run it as JavaScript you will quite rightly get errors.

Comment: Even if the file ends with .js, this is not valid javascript, or any other language I recognize. Looks more like some sort of settings file for something, but maybe someone else will know what it is, because it's surely not valid javascript.

Comment: did you write your own compiler or something?

Comment: This is iMacros: http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG_parameters_explained

Comment: Yeah, just saw a tutorial for pinterest on yourtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQjSa8ikiLQ. @Ryan Armstrong - you probably want to add "iMacrtos" to the title of this post so that ppl who know it would help.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was currently not aware that a file even with a javascript extension could still not be considered a javascript file.

Comment: @Ryan ...you can put any extension on any file, that doesn't change the contents to a different format. If you changed the extension of this to `.jpeg`, would you suddenly have a picture of something? No? Then why do you think changing it to `.js` would give you JavaScript?

Comment: I didnt change it to javascript. The file came like that.

Comment: @nbrooks I went to there site and they explained to me that error 991 is a Javascript parsing/evaluation error.

Comment: It probably is. You're trying to evaluate this as JavaScript. But it *is not JavaScript*. So *obviously* you're going to get an error parsing and evaluating it. Whether your fault or theirs. This is *not JavaScript*. Your best bet is checking one of the links above for imacros. Remember: Not. JavaScript.

Comment: This is .iim code not .js code. You've got an answer on this one bellow your post. No need to write any more.

Answer (score 2):

This is real javascript imacros code:

```
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/free_points/twitter.html" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=addmefast.com/free_points/twitter.html" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=5" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=30" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/free_points/twitter_tweets.html" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=addmefast.com/free_points/twitter_tweets.html" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=5" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Tweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=30" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/free_points/twitter_retweets.html" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=addmefast.com/free_points/twitter_retweets.html" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=5" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=30" + "\n"; 
iimPlay(macro);
```